# Does TWebBrowser updates with IE?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use TwebBrowser in a D7 app. The question is: When I upgrade my IE this component will use the new IE to render the pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

`TWebBrowser`inside of the `SHDocVw` unit internally creates a `IWebBrowser2`OLE control.

And this interface uses the the installed Internet Explorer ([as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127.aspx)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does.

When it's created, it requests the system for an instance of the object that is currently configured to implement IWebBrowser2 ({0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}) which will point to the version of IE currently installed.

Not that there is a lot of choice: you cannot have several versions of IE installed side-by-side.

it doesn't mean it will behave exactly the same between versions, though.